# Signal processing: a science or a technology on StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, scope, stackexchange

I have always thought about signal processing as a blended discipline. We already had the debate here, several times,for instance in:

- [What is Signal Processing?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/77/15892)
- [Signal Processing or Computer Science or Statistics?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1434/15892)

I woke up this morning, and found that we are not in the science tab of StackExchange:

[image: StackExchange - Science tab]
but in the technology tab instead:

[image: StackExchange - Technology tab]

I am not against dwelling close to Electrical Engineering, but I kind of believe that we (also) belong to Science folks if, well... Artificial Intelligence or Economics do.

- Should we ask for a move?
- More broady, could SE sites belong to two categories?
- Why not art?

Comment: We definitely need a spot in the science tab, preferably not too far from Mathematics.

Comment: Yeah, we could kick chemistry out, to stand right by the master

Comment: @Gilles Who can be in charge for requiring this move ?

Comment: I am not sure, maybe the mods could forward this on [meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Comment: @Peter K. do you have any inputs on this?

Comment: i think we're we belong, but *Computer Science* belongs over in the Technology group.  i dunno.  where does *Software Engineering* live?

Answer (score 2):

> Should we ask for a move?

Yes, I would second that request although, I would not get too caught up with labels. The whole "Data Science", "Network Science" and other terms, are sitting a bit oddly with my understanding. What else does anyone expect a scientist to do other than work with data? So, independently of whether "we" are scientists or DSP can be considered "Signal Science" (...or whatever), DSP does have a place in the science.

> More broad[l]y, could SE sites belong to two categories?

It would definitely increase the DSP.SE exposure but in my mind, I would think of the primary role of a discipline rather when considering its classification...

> Why not art?

...yes, DSP definitely contributes to art too...But i am not sure how much help DSP can provide to the suitability of a chord in a scale.

Definitely things that have to do with Psychoacoustics will involve a lot of DSP because DSP is the primary way (in modern times) by which this science obtains objective quantifiable data on which it bases its inferences on. And definitely Psychoacoustics has a lot to do with Music and the perception of sound, but in terms of DSP, this is probably of a secondary nature. It can be resolved by redirection probably.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking of signal processing practice as a form of art or craft, like a surgeon: rooted in science, but requiring a lot of practice and [techne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Techne)

Comment: And that view would find me inline with it too @LaurentDuval. I guess there are two levels in this discussion. There is the plain practical (or operational one) from the point of view of the functioning of the board and the one that is applicable to the subject. I wish more "practitioners" (even beyond DSP) took such a warm view of their craft :)

Comment: "What else does anyone expect a scientist to do other than work with data? " I'd agree, with a broader sens of data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with going over to science is that you start assuming that audience is primarily specialized.  I'm sure we have all read papers where maybe a hundred of so people actually understand it, and those hundred or so people only write to the hundred or so.

In technology, you can simplify and use analogies and get most of an idea across.