# Proposing a collective DSP.SE curated resource

Tags: discussion

I have often come across posts, articles, papers that I have thought that they would be of interest to this community. [Here](https://www.universetoday.com/139650/this-is-a-photo-of-neptune-from-the-ground-esos-new-adaptive-optics-makes-ground-telescopes-ignore-the-earths-atmosphere/) is one example (posted in the chat earlier this year) and [here](https://www.camras.nl/en/blog/2018/precious-earth-and-lunar-far-side/) is a more recent one.

So, it got me thinking, how about a "resource" that we collectively curate with interesting articles from around the net?

In terms of articles, this can be some excellent freely available books, key articles in DSP (and related disciplines), interesting articles with a DSP take, interesting upcoming events, ["odd" stuff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12X-i9YHzmE) and others.

In terms of a "resource", this could be something as simple as a Tumblr blog or as "complicated" as a wiki.

What do you guys think about this? Any preference regarding a platform?

**EDIT:**

In response to Peter.K's comment: I did have a more specific view about this but I was also interested in what other people might suggest too.

I am not sure if Twitter supports this but the keyword here is "collective". In other words, this is something that should allow "all of us" (at DSP.SE) to post to.

Now, I am saying "all of us" but we might want to set a rep threshold that ensures some responsibility about the subject. Nothing too high, I was thinking that anyone>700 could be considered reasonably responsible.

Sometime ago Dan Boschen (I think) started the DSP Puzzles series of posts, which was beyond DSP in a similar way that this would be beyond DSP. Laurent Duval also has talked about [a "craft" view of DSP practice.](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/signal-processing-a-science-or-a-technology-on-stackexchange/1613#1613). That's the kind of thing I have in mind.

It might even end up being something as simple as a hashtag so that you can then create an RSS feed of those posts, or a DSP.SE chat room devoted just for this purpose (to avoid authentication, approval, etc) (?).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want the resource to do.

The three places that come to mind are:

a. A Twitter feed might be a good way to share this.

b. The website [DSPRelated](https://www.dsprelated.com/) might be a good place for your personal blog about this.

c. [Medium](https://medium.com/) is a relatively new blog / posting site that might suit.

Do you see it hosting posts by multiple people? Anyone from SE.DSP? One curator, and multiple submitters?

Comment: Hi Peter K, I provided some more information as an edit to the original question. I don't know to what extend DSPRelated and Medium support group ownership? If they do, then they would fit the bill perfectly. It would be nice to have a "secondary" place for posting things that we feel that this community would appreciate but that do not necessarily come up in the Q&A format.

Comment: Case in point, [how cool is this](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/kerberossdr-4x-coherent-rtl-sdr/x/16220649)?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the [r/DSP](https://www.reddit.com/r/DSP/) over at reddit seems to be a close fit to what I had in mind and with very minimal "fuss".

If you come across any interesting DSP links, it might be worth posting them there (?), cool articles, potential products / updates, it might be a good resource to link to too from answer posts in DSP.SE